# Replace Elements in a List with Another List

Tags: r, select, graph, igraph

I am working with R programming language.

Suppose I have the following code that randomly generates a network graph:

```
library(igraph)

#create file from which to sample from
x5 <- sample(1:100, 1000, replace=T)
#convert to data frame
x5 = as.data.frame(x5)

#create first file (take a random sample from the created file)
a = sample_n(x5, 900)
#create second file (take a random sample from the created file)
b = sample_n(x5, 900)

#combine
c = cbind(a,b)
#create dataframe
c = data.frame(c)
#rename column names
colnames(c) <- c("a","b")

graph <- graph.data.frame(c, directed=F)
graph <- simplify(graph)

plot(graph)
```

[image]

Suppose I assign a weight to each node in this graph:

```
weight_data = data.frame(id = 1:100, weight = rnorm(100, 20,2))
```

Now, I want to run a "search" this graph. I want to return nodes such that:

- The node has more than 10 neighbors
- The weight of the node is bigger than the sum of the weight of its 10 neighbors.

I tried the following approach:

```
# find number of neighbors of graph
neighbors = V(graph)

#make a file of neighbors 
neighbor_file = data.frame(V = as.vector(V(graph)),
           Count = degree(graph, v = V(graph), mode = "out"))


#select nodes with at least 10 neighbors
ten_neighbor = neighbor_file[which(neighbor_file$Count > 10), ]

    # find those 10 neighbor

all_neighbors = neighborhood(graph, order = 1, V(graph) %in% ten_neighbor$V)
```

However, from here - I do not know how I could sum the weights for all the neighbors for each of these nodes to check if the condition is satisfied. I tried this code but got an error:

```
mapply(function(a,b) a[b], all_neighbors, weight_data$weight)

Error in simple_vs_index(x, lazy_eval(args[[1]])) : 
  Unknown vertex selected
```

Had this worked, I would have replaced all element in the list with their node weights, summed these node weights, and then determined if the condition was satisfied.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) use `set.seed` when generating random numbers. (2) simplify your question by removing non-essential code. Only `ten_neighbor`, `all_neighbors` and `weight_data` are required for producing an answer and you can just `dput` them. If they are too large, reduce your graph size and use 10 nodes instead. The problem is, you spent too much time in describing your problem background, making many people feel incompetent to investigate this problem. (3) simulate your weights wisely. At the moment, my code finds no nodes.

Comment: You probably shouldn't specify `mode = "out"` in `degree(graph, v = V(graph), mode = "out")` since your graph is undirected.

Answer (score 4):

The weights for the selected nodes (with 10+ neighbors) are:

```
wt1 <- weight_data$weight[ten_neighbor$V]
```

The sums of their neighbors' weights are:

```
wt2 <- sapply(all_neighbors, function (i) sum(weight_data$weight[i]))
```

You want to select nodes such that `wt1 > wt2`:

```
ten_neighbor$V[wt1 > wt2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the code below using `ego`

```
g <- graph %>%
  set_vertex_attr(name = "weight", value = weight_data$weight)

V(g)[sapply(ego(g), function(x) length(x) > 11 & sum(x[-1]$weight) < x[1]$weight)]
```